# Connect to SQL Server using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlconnection

I am using this powershell script below to connect to an instance of sql server. I am pretty sure that my username and password are correct.

> $connectionString = "server={0};database={1};uid={2};pwd={3};"

```
$c = Get-Credential
Write-Host($ipAddress)
Write-Host  $c.username 
Write-Host  $c.GetNetworkCredential().password

$connectionString = [string]::Format( "server={0};database={1};uid={2};pwd={3};", "servername", "databasename",$c.username,$c.GetNetworkCredential().password) 
#open database connection to SQL Server

Write-Host  $connectionString
$conn = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.connectionstring = $connectionString
$conn.open

    switch ($conn.State)
{
"Open" { Write-Host "Do some work"; }
Default { Write-Host "The connection is $($conn.State).  There has been an error connecting to the database."; }
}
```

It is always falling to the default statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to $conn.open is missing the (), so it would be returning a reference to that method rather than calling it.